# Permissions for thumbnailer on device

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-touch, thumbnails, apparmor, qt5

I'm developing an application for U-Touch that gets a thumbnail from a video in C++ code using libthumbnailer system library. The app does the thumbnailing perfectly in my computer, but when i try to execute that part in a device i get

```
(vs-thumb:5759): GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.41.5/./glib/gmem.c:353: overflow allocating 4294967274*8 bytes
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unknown error when trying to extract video screenshot, return value was 133.

If i enter with adb shell and i try to do it by hand:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-/gnueabihf/thumbnailer/vs-thumb video.mp4 thumb.jpg
```

i get the error:

```
Error creating thumbnail: Failed to preroll.
```

But if i execute same console operation as su it works. So i suspect is something about the application permissions. Does anybody knows how should i configure apparmor (or any other stuff that i need) for having permissions  to execute this thumbnailer as root?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to run your application with the **unconfined** template.

In your application manifest file you should have the following lines:

```
"hooks": {
    "myapp": {
        "apparmor": "myapp.json",
        "desktop": "myapp.desktop"
    }
},
```

Then in the `myapp.json` apparmor profile, use the following snippet:

```
{
    "policy_groups": [],
    "policy_version": 1.2,
    "template": "unconfined"
}
```

See: [Application Confinement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/ApplicationConfinement)

Comment: Tank you very much. That worked perfectly for me with unconfined template. I have some doubts about that parameter since not sure if i will be able to use it in production environments. Anyway, that is the reason of the failure and I'm happy this works that way!

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a better solution than using the unconfined template. It was easier than expected... only needed to include **"video"** as part of the policy group:

```
    "policy_groups": [
        ... 
        "networking",
        "video",
        ...
    ]
```

If, aditionally, you need to access video files, you can also add "video_files_read" (only read video file) or "video_files" (complete access).

You can check all the available policy groups when developing an app in Ubuntu Sdk, into QtCreator, going to Publish tab and double click on app.apparmor file. You'll find a + symbol which will show you all the policies when clicked. You can find more information at http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/packaging-click-apps/